# Why can't sessions be stored on disk?

Tags: java, session

I am learning session right now,but i realized session just can be used while the browser is open,if the browser closed,it cannot be use,but cookies can be stored in the disk,so i can only use cookies to set 3-day log-free, so, why can't session be stored in disk?

Comment: Websites **do** use cookies (files on disk) to allow their sessions to continue across browser restarts. It depends on the site, of course. They would have to deliberately implement it. What does this have to do with Java specifically?

Comment: Also consider that session data is not usually on the client side, for security reasons. Most of the data (in particular the fact that you're logged in a website) is mostly on the server. The client usually has a key that represent the session on the server.